# Prompt Text Box that will save Outlook's Formatting

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

So I am automating emails through VBA.

I had been copy pasting the email body to one of the cells in the Excel Sheet and then pulling it for use before sending the email.

Problem is: it looks very rookie/ rudimentary (esp when i have to drag it down).

Is there a fast way to call an input box that'll remember the format of the email?

I tried calling inputBox but it doesnt save the format..

FYI my code runs fine

Comment: Just make a userform to emulate an InputBox?

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Thanks @MacroMan. Just Googled it.

Answer (score 0):

This question was solved by @macro man 's suggestion of using a UserForm.
The link below explains.
http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/userform.html